# how to handle multiple popups at the same time

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

i was asked a question if we can handle multiple popups in selenium web driver.
frankly i dont know it.

But is it the right way . Assume that we are doing it and we have 3 popups on our screen. so :

- Get the handles ( window handles of each)
- focus on a single window
- close the window
- repeat the same and close it

Please correct me if im wrong.
Thanks and Good day.
- S.K

Comment: You will have to do a SwitchFrame() to each popup and then close it..

Comment: Yes this is the right way. Get window handle of each popup window, switch to it using `driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowHandle)`, and close it using `driver.Close()`.

Comment: If you do not want to continue your test you can always use driver.quit(). This will close all the browsers instantiated by the WebDriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Faiz mentioned in the comments, a reference to each window is stored in the `driver.window_handles` array.

The first handle should be your main window, so closing popups (in Ruby) might go something like this:

```
driver.window_handles[1..-1].each do |handle|
  driver.switch_to.window(handle)
  driver.close
end
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles.first)
```

Handling a few edge cases like alerts and thrown exceptions will take a bit more code though.